# Syntax of "It seemed to be a person"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

How do you you parse this sentence?

Here's my attempt:

subj: It

verb: seemed

comp: to be a man (infinitive)

is the whole infinitive phrase the complement or is "a man" the complement, and "to be" an expletive?

Comment: Good question. The usual consensus is that (assuming _It_ refers to a real  thing, and is not a dummy _it_) _seem_ is an intransitive flip perception verb that optionally takes an experiencer in a _to_-phrase (_seems to me/him/everybody_) and takes a subject complement clause, which must either undergo Extraposition (with _that_-complements) or [Subject-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) (with infinitive complements). E.g, **For him to be tired seems* Raises to _He seems to be tired_, but **That he is tired seems* Extraposes to _It seems that he is tired_.

Comment: @John Lawler He probably wants an answer that his teacher 'understands', not a/the proper one.

Comment: Well, the infinitive **is** the complement, or what's left of it (minus the raised _It_ subject), and the whole infinitive phrase **is** the complement, right enough. At least close enough.

Answer (score 1):

'It' is not always a real subject but a grammatical construct so that a sentence which does not need a subject has one, as in "It is raining." This usage is sometimes called 'dummy subject'.

Your sentence actually does not have a subject but English grammar requires a subject. So 'it' is used in lieu of a subject. (In other languages it is common to omit the subject and have the verb conjugation hint which omitted pronoun would be the subject.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. 
"Seem to" is a phrasal modal and not the main/lexical verb.

```
sbj: it
vrb: seemed to - be
        cmp: person
                det: a
```

That's all it is. This actually simplifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly, in the copular/linking verbs as "appear" & "seem" we often use 'TO BE' for showing a relationship or describing a state. It is better to regard "seem to be" as verb phrase. "A man" is the complement.

Otherwise, "seem" may take a clause/ phrase as its complement.

° It seems that it would rain today.

°°I seem to have left my book at home.

In the last sentence "to have" is not the part of the verb phrase but part of an elliptical clause--"to have left my book at home".

Comment: So you claim the structure of "It seemed to be a man." is different from "It seemed to run quickly." ?

Comment: @ Ben Voigt exactly. In the 1st. 'Man' is the complement and in the 2nd.'to run quickly' meaning a crammed version of "that it would run quickly"--- both functioning as complement.